# Dijkstra's Algorithm - Initializing Node Distances

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

I have an assignment to use Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm for a simple network simulation. There's one part of the coding implementation that I don't understand and it's giving me grief.
I searched around on stack overflow and found many helpful questions about Dijkstra's, but none with my specific question. I apologize if I didn't research thoroughly enough.

I'm using this pseudocode from Mark Allen Weiss's Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++:

```
void Graph::dijkstra( Vertex s)
{
    for each Vertex v
    {
        v.dist = INFINITY;
        v.known = false;
    }

    s.dist = 0;

    while( there is an unknown distance vertex )
    {
         Vertex v = smallest unknown distance vertex;
         v.known = true;

         for each Vertex w adjacent to v
         {
             if (!w.known)
             {
                 int cvw = cost of edge from v to w;
                 if(v.dist + cvw < w.dist)
                 {
                      //update w
                      decrease(w.dist to v.dist + cvw);
                      w.path = v;
                 }
             }

     }
}
```

and my implementation seems to work aside from the last `if` statement.

```
if(v.dist + cvw < w.dist)
```

My code will never go into what's underneath because the distance for every node is initialized to (essentially) infinity and the algorithm never seems to change the distance. Therefore the left side of the comparison is never smaller than the right side. How am I misunderstanding this?

Here is my (messy) code:

```
class Vertex
{
private:
  int id;
  unordered_map < Vertex*, int > edges;
  int load_factor;
  int distance;
  bool known;
public:
        //getters and setters
};

void dijkstra(Vertex starting_vertex)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
  {
    //my program initially stores vertices in the vertex in spot (id - 1).

    if (vertices[i].get_id() == starting_vertex.get_id())
    {
      vertices[i].set_distance(0);
      vertices[i].set_known(true);
    }
    else
    {
      vertices[i].set_distance(10000000);
      vertices[i].set_known(false);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
  {
    //while there is an unknown distance vertex
    if (vertices[i].is_known() == false)
    {
      vertices[i].set_known(true);

      //for every vertex adjacent to this vertex
      for (pair<Vertex*, int> edge : vertices[i].get_edges())
      {
        //if the vertex isn't known
        if (edge.first->is_known() == false)
        {
          //calculate the weight using Adam's note on dijkstra's algorithm
          int weight = edge.second * edge.first->get_load_factor();

          if (vertices[i].get_distance() + weight < edge.first->get_distance())
          //this is my problem line. The left side is never smaller than the right.
          {
            edge.first->set_distance(vertices[i].get_distance() + weight);
            path.add_vertex(edge.first);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing out this step:

```
Vertex v = smallest unknown distance vertex;
```

and instead looping through all vertices.

The distance to the starting vertex is initialized to `0` so if you implement this part of the algorithm and pick the `v` with the smallest distance that is not "known" you will start with the starting vertex and the `if` should work.

Replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
{
  //while there is an unknown distance vertex
  if (vertices[i].is_known() == false)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

With something like:

```
while(countNumberOfUnknownVertices(vertices) > 0)
{
  Vertex& v = findUnknownVertexWithSmallestDistance(vertices);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed two important parts of Dijkstra's Algorithm.

In implementing

```
while( there is an unknown distance vertex )
{
    Vertex v = smallest unknown distance vertex;
```

you set v to the *first* unknown vertex you come to. It's supposed to be, of *all* the unknown vertices, the one whose distance is least.

The other misstep is that, instead of making one pass over the vertices and doing some work on each unknown one you find, you need to search again after doing the work.

For example, if on one iteration you expand outward from vertex 5, that may make vertex 3 the new unknown vertex with least distance. You can't just continue the search from 5.

The search for the least-distance unknown vertex is going to be slow unless you develop some data structure (a Heap, perhaps) to make that search fast. Go ahead and do a linear search for now. Dijkstra's Algorithm will still work, but it'll take time O(N^2). You should be able to get it down to at least O(N log N).